# Switching to HP microserver

Tags: linux, hp, migration, vmware-server

I wonder if anybody have experience with migrating to the latest Gen8 HP microserver from existing architectures.

http://www.storagereview.com/hp_proliant_microserver_gen8_review

In my case the server what I would migrate would have 2X  Intel® Xeon® Processor E5450 (12M Cache, 3.00 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB) and 24 GB ram and I would replace this with 1X Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1220L v2 (3M Cache, 2.30 GHz) and 16GB ram.

Looking at the CPU comparison, this would result in a much slower server:
http://ark.intel.com/compare/33083,65735,71074

I would be running 8-10 lightly loaded Vmware vms on top of it. Only used by 1-5 users irregularly. Would I notice significant degradation in performance?

Thanks

Comment: Performance is _very_ hard to predict, especially since we aren't talking about only changing one parameter and the load isn't constant and predictable. The only real answer is testing/benchmarking your particular usecase

Comment: I dont  think it's a duplicate and can be very interesting for many of those who do similar switch to microservers from old but more powerful servers. Here is the cpu load with the old server http://tinypic.com/r/16leikg/8 I think the new one should be able to handle this with the same amount of users. I did not order the server yet otherwise I would do the benchmark myself.